# Defining SSAS roles in other domain

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I am developing SSAS cubes for a customer. Now I am developing on my PC in my company' domain. Is it possible to define roles and security options based on my customer's domain and active directory groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you cannot add them through the designer, it is possible to edit the source XML files of your AS project. Roles are saved in your solution directory in files with the '.role' file extension.

Modify the members of your role using this XML construct:

```
<Members>
    <Member>
        <Name>Domain\GroupOrUserName</Name>
    </Member>
</Members>
```

It might also be a good idea to predefine your roles, but let your server administrator/DBA add members to them in production.

Afterwards, you can deploy new versions of your SSAS database while retaining the security settings on your cube through [Analysis Services Deployment wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176121).